# Port forward MZ to DMZ to public

Tags: linux, linux-networking, port, port-forwarding

We need to forward port 993 from my MZ server to DMZ server to Mail Server . Actually port 993 are open from my DMZ server to mail server . Application is running on MZ and login to mail server script run on MZ server. we need to authenticate mail server Users from MZ through DMZ server. DMZ has access on 993 port to mail server. but when we try to login or access MZ to mail server its not getting access.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried iptables?

Someting like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:993
```

Where 10.10.10.10 represents the destination. You have to issue the command on your public accessable Server. eth0 represents in this case the public WAN interface. Repeat that on the DMZ Server